# tensorflow's svm works with gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, svm, libsvm

as you know the SVM in ski-learn doesn't support GPU. by the way, the Tensorflow has a SVM module but I don't know tensorflow's svm works on GPU or not? if it doesn't support GPU can I force it to use GPU by code?

Comment: Does something like this help? https://learningtensorflow.com/lesson10/

Comment: "if it doesn't support GPU can I force it to use GPU by code?" How should that work? If it would not be supported how should you "force" it?